# Is there a way to tell if sign up activation email was sent successfully from Azure APIM Developer Portal?

Tags: azure-api-management, apim

We're using the Managed Developer Portal in Azure API Management (APIM). When signing up, a user should receive an email to confirm their account.

Has anyone found a way to troubleshoot when users report not receiving an email? I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation or GitHub Issues for the Managed Developer Portal.

https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal

Answer (score 0):

This can be achievable using self hosted API management for which you need to implement an endpoint on your portal
**GET /confirm-v2/identities/basic/signup**

and then this endpoint should convert the request to MAPI call
POST {**managementApiUrl**}/users/{**userId**}/identities/Basic/{**identity**}?api-version={**managementApiVersion**}
with "Authorization": **token**

You can get the token, userid, identity  from request query string parameter

for token authorization you can add header "**Ticket id={ticketId},ticket={ticket}**"

for further details check the [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal#managed-vs-self-hosted) and [Github](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/460#issuecomment-582576606)